# Querying all users that have a role in Azure Active Directory using MS Graph SDK

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

I want to query all users in Azure Active Directory who have an app role assigned to.

I am looking for something like this:

```
private readonly GraphServiceClient _graphServiceClient;

....

var users = await _graphServiceClient.Users
    .Request()
    .Filter(....) <- Here I add the values of the roles, or ids
    .GetAsync();
```

I only found [this solution](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-approleassignments?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) where I should query all the user, and then for each user check if he has that role assigned. I think it is a solution with a high time and resources consuming. So I am looking for something better, but I did not find anything.

Any suggestions?

PS.: When I say `value` i mean that:

[image]

The image above is from the Owned Application in Azure Active Directory. Those are my custom roles. When I create a custom role I must add also the `value`.

Via code you can find it with this code:

```
var application = await _graphServiceClient.Applications["65356eb3-fbd8-428c-bee5-a2da05e55fdb"]
    .Request()
    .Select("appRoles")
    .GetAsync();
```

[image]
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

There should be two ways how to achieve this.

One way is to expand `appRoleAssignments` relationship and filter app roles by `resourceId`

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$expand=appRoleAssignments&$filter=appRoleAssignments/any(r:r/resourceId eq {resourceId})&$count=true
Header ConsistencyLevel:eventual
```

Code

```
GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient( authProvider );
var queryOptions = new List<QueryOption>()
{
    new QueryOption("$count", "true")
};

var users = await graphClient.Users
    .Request( queryOptions )
    .Header("ConsistencyLevel","eventual")
    .Filter("appRoleAssignments/any(r:r/resourceId eq {resourceId})")
    .Expand("appRoleAssignments")
    .GetAsync();
```

Another way is to use `$filter` in `$expand` clause

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$expand=appRoleAssignments($filter=resourceId eq {resourceId})
```

Code

```
GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient( authProvider );

var users = await graphClient.Users
    .Request()
    .Expand("appRoleAssignments($filter=resourceId+eq+{resourceId})")
    .GetAsync();
```

Bad news is that the first way returns `BadRequest` with error message `"Expect simple name=value query, but observe property 'appRoleAssignments' of complex type 'AppRoleAssignment'."` which usually means that filtering is not supported.

For the second way the `$filter` is ignored in `$expand` clause.

So, what you can do is to get all `users` with expanded `appRoleAssignments` and filter users on the client.

```
var users = await graphClient.Users
    .Expand("appRoleAssignments")
    .GetAsync();
```

Comment: Thnk you... It works.. just one thing... I should filter roles by value... I added an image to be sure I am clear in what I mean...

Comment: @Ciccio Value is a property on User object? It's not clear for me...

Comment: I  edited my question to be more clear. That `Value` is a property on Role object. But I am thinking I am asking for a "dirty" solution. Perhaps I should work with id, not value... So perhaps I should "copy" roles from AAD to my personal DB